# PHP: mysqli_multi_query with mysql_rollback

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been doing some research and have not found a complete answer if I can use `mysqli_multi_query` that may contain both Updates/Deletes, while using `mysql_rollback` in the event that one of the queries fails.  Does anyone know if this can be done?  If so, any simple example I could build off of?

The only examples and information I have seen is simple query by query with auto commit disabled, then committing at the end, with the option of rollback in the event of an issue.

Comment: With questions like these I would just setup a simple db, create some queries, run them with the mysql_multi_query function (offcourse add 1 query that doesn't work) and then try rolling back the changes. Also you are talking about mysqli in the first function and mysql in the second one.

Comment: Sorry, should have been mysqli_rollback.  Yeah, I was thinking that as well, I will likely do that in a bit, was hoping for some insight before I did.  Thanks

Comment: @DennisHepworth This should explain it a bit further for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649926/how-does-mysqlicommit-mysqlirollback-work